# How to Iso Date as String in Access

Tags: ms-access

Can someone please tell me how to convert ISO date showing as short text in my access table to date?  Here is an example 2014-12-18T05:00:00 as short text in my access table.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
TrueDate = CDate(Replace(TextDate, "T", " "))
```

Or in a query:

```
TrueDate: CDate(Replace([TextDateFieldName],"T"," "))
```